# winding number and Jordan-Schoenflies Theorem

Tags: differential-topology, knot-invariants

I have a statement which is related to the
smooth Jordan-Schoenflies Theorem.
I can verify it in some simple cases.

The setup is:
Let there be a $C^1$ immersion $\gamma : S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.
Assume it is in general position, i.e. there are a finite number of
self-intersections and all of them are transverse double-points.
Then the complement $\mathbb{R}^2 - \gamma(S^1)$ has a finite number
of open connected components and the winding number of $\gamma$ is
constant on each component.
Let the components be $U_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,N$ and the corresponding
winding numbers be $w_i$.

The statement is:

$\gamma$ has a $C^1$ extension $\Gamma : D^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$
so that if $y \in U_i$,
then $y$ is a regular value of $\Gamma$,
and the signed sum over the points in $\Gamma^{-1}(y)$ is equal to $w_i$.
The signs are the usual ones: +1 if $\Gamma$ preserves orientation
at the point and -1 if $\Gamma$ reverses orientation.

Is it true ?

In the case that $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve (with no self-intersections),
it is true by the smooth Jordan-Schoenflies Theorem.
There are only 2 components $U_1$ and $U_2$  (inside and outside),
with winding numbers $w_1=\pm 1$ and $w_2=0$.

This might be related to the Reidemeister moves in knot theory.